# Can't figure out NSDateFormatter symbols

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
    NSString * dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",item.date];

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
    NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd / M / Y 'ás' HH:mm ZZZZ"];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];
```

The data comes in like.... 2014-08-15T08:30:00-04:00

I want this date to be .... 15 - 08 - 2014 12:00

I want the date to be displayed in GMT format, or at least to show the right local time that the event starts, wether you live in US or Japan, and to not display the GMT timezone.

I've tried Z ZZ ZZZ ZZZZ ZZZZZ z zz zzz zzzz

nothing... can anyone help?

Comment: Just mentioning, you should have a look at NSDateFormatter's date and time *styles*. They're much easier and less errorprone to use than dateFormats. The latter should be used if for example you parse a date from an external source like a web service.

Comment: @JiaYow Oh, no. Styles are subject to what the user chooses in their System Preferences. The user can quite innocently break your application if you rely on date formatter styles. If used, they should be used only to determine what should be displayed, rather than interpreting a date string.

Comment: you can show your system time zone with  NSTimeZone *timeZone=[NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

Comment: @trudyscousin I was not talking about "interpretation" but about display. OP wanted to *display* the time in some format (as far as I understood), and for this, I would definitely go with the user's system preferences choice. As I said, he should use dateformat for parsing, and style for display.

Comment: @JiaYow I won't argue semantics with you. The OP is interpreting a date string.

Comment: @trudyscousin He's doing both. If it wasn't clear that I was referring to his second operation, sorry 'bout that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
NSString * dateString = @"2014-08-15T08:30:00-04:00";

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

//[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSLog(@"date--%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate]);

output--`date--15-08-2014 18:00:00`
```

Comment: There is no need to set the date formatter's timezone to the local timezone - that is the default.

Comment: yes , i have written it to give a basic idea, if anyone want to change the timezone.

Comment: And `Z` can't be used for a timezone in the format `-xx:xx`. For that you need `ZZZZZ`.

Comment: @rmaddy: `Z` actually works in iOS 7, but not in iOS 6. But you are right that the documented format is `ZZZZZ`.

Comment: According to the spec, `ZZZZZ` is for the `+xx:xx` format but perhaps `Z` can be used for parsing while `ZZZZZ` would be needed for formatting.

Comment: i don't want the GMT+-5:30 , i want it to show the time in GMT without the GMT +/-xxxxxx text or in the user local time, again without the gmt

Comment: if you dont GMT value, remove the ZZZZ. the output will be 15-08-2014 18:00:00

Comment: @MartinR  what if i want this to work with ios6 . what this"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" should be.

Comment: @pawan: As rmaddy said: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"`.

Comment: ok, so it always gives you the time converted to your local time I'm assuming

Comment: sure , system time zone is by default.